# Jquery Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am using these links:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
```

And then this in the script: `$( "#draggable" ).draggable();`

It shows an error `$(...).draggable` is not a function.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the script written? `<script>` tag or .js file?

Comment: Have you included jquery.js?

Comment: you may forgot to include the library that contains draggable function\

Comment: The script is within the script tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `#draggable` does not exist when you try to reach it. You might try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    $(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am actually trying to write an NFL division quiz. The idea is that a team logo appears and the player has to move it to the correct division.  Obviously there is only one correct division , so if the player attemps to drop it in a different one, it is returned to the original position.

Comment: <script> 
   $ (function () {
    $( "#teamLogo").draggable();
     $( ".droppable").droppable({drop: function( event, ui ) {if $(".droppable").css ("id","AFCSouth") {
           alert ("Drop correct!");
        }
       else {
        $( this ).draggable({revert: true});
       }
      }
     });
    })
   
 </script>

Comment: If the answer answers your question and the error message no longer appears, then you might consider accepting my answer. Also, if you create a fiddle about your actual problem, link it into a comment, then I might be able to give you further help.

Comment: @LajosArpad Thanks!

Comment: @LADYX You are welcome